# Two concurent Eclipse versions on my laptop, wrong one launched from the shortcut

Tags: icons, eclipse, shortcuts, paths

I have an old eclipse version already installed on my laptop, I installed neo from the official website. now I have two concurrent versions of eclipse. **I want to launch the last version when I click on the desktop graphical shortpath. Yet this lunch the oldest one.**

[image]

In order to have the right eclipse version (neon). I have to use the command line :

[image]

Do you know how can I cope wiht this issue? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have the `eclipse` package installed, which is usually a few versions behind the most recent Eclipse release provided on their website.

However, it's possible that if you remove the package you will no loger "need" Java installed, which will cause it to auto uninstall that packege. So you should remove the eclipse package and then manually install whatever JDK you are using, like this:

```
 sudo apt-get remove eclipse*
 sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

You will have to drag the Eclipse launcher for Neon from the directory to Unity. Also, for some reason this causes the icon to no longer match the Eclipse icon, and I don't have an easy solution for that.